# Microsoft Teams - Parameters for HTTPPost in webhook

Tags: json, http-post, microsoft-teams

I have created a simple incoming webhook for Teams that will send information to a channel when a new high-priority ticket is generated in our ticketing system.  I want to add a button to the connector card that will allow a user to directly assign the ticket to themselves from Teams via an HttpPOST request.

I have the button and everything else in place, but I am having trouble determining how, if possible, I can send the user's account ID back to our ticketing system.  Our system is connected via LDAP so usernames are the same across both platforms.

Is there general info on what is sent by default with an HttpPOST request?  I looked through the Teams connector reference information, but could not find what I was looking for.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to include that account id you referred as a parameter in your url or JSON (if you post the it).

Microsoft Teams does not know anything about actions your use will attempt to make.

Comment: I'm more looking to send the user ID as a variable.  I was hoping Teams had a way of parameterizing the username of the person clicking the button so I could send that parameter to our system.  For example, Slack's API has a 'user.identity' method that delivers the id and name of the user triggering it.  Teams should have something similar.

Comment: Makes a lot of sense. I liked your idea so I created a [UserVoice](https://microsoftteams.uservoice.com/forums/555103-public/suggestions/32004619-support-for-passing-basic-profile-info-in-connecto) for it. Feel free to vote and provide additional comments.

Comment: As you see @BillyHudgins, it is not supported as I said. Slack also does not save the mapping between systems, it does help you a bit, bit account binding is our with you job :)